# How to configure vlan mapping with VPLS on Cisco 6500 routers?

Tags: vlan, cisco-catalyst, vpls

I'm using VPLS to extend vlan x from site1 (Cisco C6500) to two remotes sites (Cisco C6500) site2 and site3 over MPLS. 
The issue I'm facing is that a vlan with the same number already exists in the remote site3, so I'm using a different vlan number (say y) in the remote site3. How do I configure vlan mapping between site1 and site3 to map vlan y to x and vice versa?
Thanks!

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve VLAN mapping between site1 and site3 in VPLS, you can use the VLAN Translation feature on the Cisco Catalyst 6500 routers. This feature allows you to map VLANs between different sites in a VPLS network. Here's a general outline of the steps to configure VLAN mapping:

Identify the VLANs to be mapped: Determine which VLANs need to be mapped between site1 and site3. For example, if you have VLAN x in site1 and VLAN y in site3, you want to map VLAN y to VLAN x and vice versa.

Configure VPLS on both routers: Set up VPLS on both the site1 and site3 Cisco Catalyst 6500 routers. This involves configuring the VPLS instance, specifying the MPLS pseudowire, and defining the VFI (Virtual Forwarding Instance).

Configure VLAN translation on both routers: Use the "bridge-domain vlan-translation" command to configure VLAN translation on the VFI for both VLANs x and y. For example:

```
Router (config)# bridge-domain vlan-translation vlan x map y
Router (config)# bridge-domain vlan-translation vlan y map x
```

Verify the configuration: Use the "show bridge-domain" command to verify that the VLAN translation is correctly configured on both routers.